# How to change from Table to Card in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering the products in a table but I want to display them as card. Every time I touch the code it stops working, I've tried mixing them together but nothing, any suggestions?

```
function Products(props) {
  function Products(products) {
    if (products === null) return;
    return products.map((product) => (
      <ListGroup.Item key={product.Id}>
        <Link to={`/products/${product.name}`} key={product.id}> {product.name}
        </Link>
      </ListGroup.Item>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <Stack direction="horizontal" gap={3}>
        <ListGroup className="align-self-start w-75">
          <ProductContext.Consumer>
            {({ products }) => Products(products)}
          </ProductContext.Consumer>
        </ListGroup>
        <Outlet />
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: You've posted only `JSX` but it needs more information like `state`...

Comment: Show us what you tried.Are you using a specific UI toolkit or is it just bare HTML? If HTML, what do you want a card to be?

Comment: Just posted the updated file.

Comment: I really appreciate any suggestion!